# Android: auto-resize for each device

Tags: java, android, resize

I've create a very simple app and i download it in 15 different devices. For some of them the layout have no resize problem and appear like this:

[Layout that should be in all layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjJK8.jpg)

But when i installed the app in a Sansung Galaxy Neo Plus and in the tablet Archos 101 Copper the items' layout were not in the position that i want. In the tablet are up of the background different color view and in the Galaxy Neo Plus are like this:
[Layout in the Galaxy Neo Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF7AC.jpg)

To auto-resize, in the activities xml, i used thse codes:

```
android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
```

to set the buttons' margin from top/bottom/left/right

```
android:textSize="30dp"
```

to set the size of buttons' text

The layout code is this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Al meglio di:"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/almegliodi"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" UNO "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/uno"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
    android:onClick="uno"
    android:layout_below="@+id/almegliodi"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" TRE "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/tre"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
    android:onClick="tre"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/uno"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" CINQUE "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/cinque"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
    android:onClick="cinque"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tre"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ESCI"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/esci"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="esci"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="INDIETRO"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/indietro"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="indietro"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/esci"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout
```

I searched on google but i found that use the 'dp' is the best way to auto-resize margin and text in all device.

What are my mistakes? What i have to do to solve the compatibility?

Thank you

Comment: Please add your layout. In general you should use a linear layout with weights to fix that

Comment: Possibly, you aren't using the correct density buckets. The ones for tablets differ greatly from those for phones.

Comment: @rekire i added my layouts but only by links beacause i have no enough reputation to post image directly

Comment: You can add them as text ;-) Better to edit

Comment: @rekire i add the layout code

Comment: Great, did you check in the meantime my example below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how your layout could look like:

[image: Example]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#005"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cfff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You should of cause use `@string/` for each button to make your app translatable, but that basic layout should give you the right idea how to make a layout which scales correctly.

Basically I use some linear layouts which just say how the views should been arranged (horizontal or vertical). Then I told the view which contains the three main buttons that its height should be zero (just for performance) and the most important part that the layout weight is 1 (`android:layout_weight="1"`) that tells the system to split up the open space to all views with a weight attribute. So this one will fill your display as far as possible. The other views will still been rendered as you want in my case `wrap_content`.

Comment: Why have you used the android.support.v4.widget.Space for weight in the 3rd layout? And in the 2nd do you put the weight in the layout general proprieties? What is the utility of the sace widget?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is basically a place holder which will not been displayed, but it takes the room to allow you to have one view at the right and one at the left. That was the quickest way to get that result.

Comment: and if i want to ingrease the margin from the 2nd layout and the imageview? I can use the marginTop? Or there is an other function in linear layout?

Comment: Basically you can use padding and margin as in CSS if you are familiar with that. Just keep in mind when you want one different value you have to write 4 attributes instead of one (padding vs paddingTop, paddingButtom,  paddingLeft and paddingRight).

Comment: ok the padding works but putting the margintop (for exemple in the second layout),it doas not change nothing
---edit---no ok it works i didn't see the already exist margin item that you wrote :)

Comment: ok i tried this code in my phone (GlaxyS4) and in a tablet 10'' and i have to ask something: in the screen that you send the button are the truth dimendion for the screen, but with this code , in the tablet this buttons are in center of the layout but are very smal...how can i do for set them in the same way that are in the phone? Same dimension scale?

Comment: If you want that the buttons are filling its parent set them to `match_parent`. It is normal to have special optimizations for small and large tablets, so you can use the suffixed I guess ***`-sw533dp`*** and ***`-sw720dp`*** for big tablets. To be honest that 533 suffix is not very common but this will keep a Kindle tablet (HD7) as a tablet and not a phone. So you could use dimmens for that special treatment or a special layout, you must decide this for you. In my choice the layout would be in ***`layout/main.xml`***, ***`layout-sw533dp/main.xml`*** and ***`layout-sw720dp/main.xml`***.

Comment: and an other questions...for a good auto-size of text and margin you advice to use dp or sp? Because i used dp but on internet the guides and other programmers advice to use sp

Comment: which do you advice to use?

Comment: It always depends on your needs, in general sp is better since it is a well defined font size and if you setup your device to use a bigger font size it will work also in your app. In other words: use sp, except you have a good reason not to use it.